# MySQL: update table values with DATE FORMAT %d-%m-%y TO %y-%m-%d

Tags: mysql, date-formatting

During a database import, I kinda messed things up. So now I have a date column that is of `DATE` type, but the year and day are in the wrong places: the day ended up appearing in the year column and MySQL has auto formatted it as year further worsening things.

I have values in a table like below:

```
dates(dddd-mm-yy)
2030-05-12
2021-06-13
2012-12-13
```

I want them like so:

```
dates(yyyy-mm-dd)
2012-05-30
2013-06-21
2013-12-12
```

Please note that I actually want to `UPDATE` the column, I have seen and tried many examples on `SELECT`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type is this column? `varchar`?

Comment: @JPG My column is in DATE type

Comment: @JPG I have edited my question a little. Thnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this can be classified a "solution", maybe more of a work around, but it worked flawless for me.

After reading [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html), i realised that my problem started when i tried to import my dates in the format dd-mm-yy, Hence Mysql assumed my day to be year and presented my dates as yydd-mm-yy

My dates were formatted as yydd-mm-yy and i have severally tried the query

```
UPDATE table_name
SET DATES =  DATE_FORMAT(DATES, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

This query ran but made no changes to the Table because in the eyes of Mysql it has helped me format my dates as yyyy-mm-dd right from when i imported my DB, but still my dates are in yydd-mm-dd

So i thought, what if i try a query like;

```
UPDATE table_name
SET DATES =  DATE_FORMAT(DATES, '%d-%m-%y');
```

This way Mysql switched the days and years then provided my dates as yyyy-mm-dd, quite a confusing thing the way Mysql handles dates but the end result of a date like 2030-05-12 is 2012-05-30.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring() and concat() to concat whatever you want. Below is the statement for your reference(table is tb_test, the column name is col_date).

```
update tb_test set col_date = concat('20',substring(col_date,7,2),'-',substring(col_date,4,2),'-',substring(col_date,1,2));
```

Comment: Nice attempt. But i am messing with a very large DB here. Some of those dates go back to 1990's

Comment: I was imagining a 2 query solution though. One to switch the days and years position and the other to just tell mysql to auto-generate the remaining part of the years. I dnt knw hw such would be done in script tho.

Comment: If the column type is date, it's easy to use DATE_FORMAT(date_col, '%y-%m-%d') to covert it. I suggest to use another column to store the updated date value. For example: update tb_test set new_date_col = DATE_FORMAT(date_col, '%y-%m-%d');

Comment: i had tried that too. Query executed but did not update my column. I have edited my question a little thought. Thx